# Watson API on Node.js: error invalid text representation

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I'm using Watson API on my Node.js application. I successfully connected my application with the API, but I when I run my app I got this message:

> "error invalid text representation"

This is my code :

```
var watson = require('watson-developer-cloud');

var conversation = watson.conversation({
  url: 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation-experimental/api',  
  username: '*********',
  password: '*******',
  version: 'v1',
  version_date: '2016-07-01'
});
// req.body.text
conversation.message({
  input: 'what is your name', 
  workspace_id: '***'
 }, function(err, response) {
     if (err) {
       console.error(err);
     } else {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
     }
});
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the url is correct? When the service instance is created on bluemix a url is provided as a part of the credentials. The config you have above suggests you are using the v1 API but it is trying to hit the experimental service? If the url, as provided by the service is https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api then you can just remove it, as that is the default which is handled by the SDK

Answer (score 0):

your URL and version seems to be wrong..

Try this:

```
conversation.message({
  input: {
    text: 'what is your name'
  }, 
  workspace_id: '***'
 }, function(err, response) {
     if (err) {
       console.error(err);
     } else {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
     }
});
```

You have to add a 'text' to your JSON